# JQuery Masonry. Ajax icon and "load new items" string is misplaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am using the JQuery plug-in called *Masonry*.

In order to learn how it works I downloaded a demo and then manually stripped out all non essential code.

What I am left with is here:

http://helpknow.com/black2

The problem I am having is when I scroll to the bottom of the page an AJAXY-looking icon is *supposed* to appear hence symbolizing new "in progress" page loads.This does not happen.

Also, when you get to the very bottom you should see a string that says "No more pages to load."

This does not happen either. The string doesn't appear at the bottom of the page, it appears at the *top* when you scroll back up.

I don't know how to fix these two problems.

Thank you.

Comment: couple of things: 1 - can you post a link to the Masonry jquery plugin? 2 - probably better if you post your source to something like [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) where it's a lot easier to see and edit the code you are working on. 3 - for the in progress...might it be that the pages are simply loading too fast for the icon to even show up?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/taoist/2CtwD/   (non working)                      The original plug in page is http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: the problem seems to be with infinite scroll plugin, not with masonry. am i right?

Comment: Actually yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use css styles to position the div.

something like this:

```
#infscr-loading {
position: fixed;
bottom:7px;
right:7px;
}
```